# Tangent and normal to ellipse

Tags: analytic-geometry

I'm stuck with this question here.

> Find the equation of the normal at the point $x=a\cos\theta$, $y=b\sin\theta$, of the ellipse $\frac {x^2}{a^2} +\frac{ y^2}{b^2} = 1$. The normal at $P$ on the ellipse meets the major axes of the ellipse at $N$. Show that the locus of the mid point of $PN$ is an ellipse and state the lengths of the principal axes.

I'm only able to obtain the equation of the normal: $$\frac{y\cos\theta}{a} - \frac{x\sin\theta}{b^2} = \frac{\sin\theta\cos\theta}{a^2} - \frac{\sin\theta\cos\theta}{b^2}$$

I've problem with proving one thing is another. Please help

Comment: Your equation for the normal line is wrong.

Comment: Where have I gone wrong here? I got my gradient to the normal as asin∅/bcos∅ and substituted into the normal equation: y-y¹=m(x-x¹). So pls enlighten more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the given parametric expressions we have the derivative of the coordinates with respect to the parameter as
$$\left\{ \begin{aligned} x &= a \cos\theta \\
y &= b \sin\theta
\end{aligned}
\right. \quad \implies \left\{ \begin{aligned} \dot{x} &= -a \sin\theta \\
\dot{y} &= b \cos\theta
\end{aligned} \right. \qquad \text{where}~~ \dot{x} \equiv \frac{dx}{d\theta},~\dot{y} \equiv \frac{dy}{d\theta}~.$$
Thus the slope of the tangent line at point $P = (a\cos\theta, b\sin\theta)$ is 
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{ \dot{y} }{ \dot{x} } = -\frac{ b\cos\theta}{a\sin\theta}~,$$
and the slope of the normal line is the negative inverse of that:
$$m \equiv -\left( \frac{dy}{dx} \right)^{-1} = \frac{ -\dot{x} }{ \dot{y} } = \frac{ a\sin\theta}{ b\cos\theta}~.$$
Note that here the parameter happens to be the polar angle, therefore $m$ is just the $\tan\theta$ (the slope of a normal line to a circle at $\theta$ angle) scaled by $\frac{a}b$.

The equation to the normal line is thus 
$$ \frac{ y - b\sin\theta }{ x - a\cos\theta } = m = \frac{ a\sin\theta}{ b\cos\theta}~,$$ 
or equivalently
$$y - b \sin\theta = \frac{ a\sin\theta}{ b\cos\theta} (x - a\cos\theta)~ \tag*{Eq.(1)} $$
or to compare it with what is stated in the question post:
$$\frac{ y \cos\theta }a  - \frac{ x \sin\theta }b = \frac{ b^2 - a^2}{ ab} \sin\theta \cos\theta ~.$$

Denote $(x_0, y_0)$ as the coordinates of point $N$, the intersection of the normal line with the major axis (which is also the $x$-axis). The $x$-coordinate is readily calculated with $\text{Eq.}\,\text{(1)}$ at $y_0 = 0$

\begin{align}
&& y_0 - b \sin\theta &= \frac{ a\sin\theta}{ b\cos\theta} (x_0 - a\cos\theta) \\
&\implies & \frac{ - b^2 }a \cos\theta  &= x_0 - a\cos\theta \\
&\implies &  x_0 &= \left( a - \frac{ b^2 }a \right) \cos\theta 
\end{align}
Denoting $r \equiv a - \frac{ b^2 }a  = \frac{ a^2 - b^2 }a $, we have the center of the line segment $\overline{PN}$ being at
$$ \left( \frac{ x + x_0}2 ~, \frac{ y + y_0}2\right) =  \left( \frac{ a + r}2 \cos\theta ~, \frac{ b}2 \sin\theta\right) =  \left( \frac{ 2a^2 - b^2}{ 2 a }  \cos\theta ~, \frac{ b}2 \sin\theta\right) $$
At this point, we can identify the requested locus as an ellipse centere at the same origin and parametrized (necessarily) by the same parameter $\theta$ with the principle axes
$$a' \equiv \frac{ 2a^2 - b^2}{ 2 a} = a - \frac{b^2}{ 2a } ~~, ~~b' \equiv \frac{b}2$$

### Further Discussion

Note that the ratio $\frac{ a' }{ b'} \neq \frac{a}b$. That is, the new ellipse is NOT similar to the original. Nor does the ratio equal to $\sqrt{ \frac{a}b }$ or $\frac{a^2}{ b^2}$ or anything particularly nice. What we can say about the shape is that this new ellipse (from the locus) is more "elongated" than the original. Consider the wide-and-short original ellipse where $a > b$, we have
$$ \frac{ a' }{ b'} = \frac{2a}b - \frac{b}a = \frac{a}b + \left( \frac{a}b - \frac{b}a \right) > \frac{a}b $$
where the larger ratio gives a more stretched out ellipse.

Also note that the locus goes "outside" of the original two foci,
$$a' > \sqrt{a^2 - b^2} \qquad \because (a')^2 = a^2 - b^2 + \frac{ b^4 }{ 4a^2 } > a^2 - b^2$$
with its own foci that are closer to the center.
$$(a')^2 - (b')^2  = a^2 - b^2 + \frac{ b^2}4 \left( \frac{ b^2 }{ a^2 } - 1\right) < a^2 - b^2$$

Comment: Thanks. I really appreciate your response

Comment: @MichaelUmande Glad I could help. After you have read it in details and verified that my math is correct, then you may consider clicking on the green check mark to accept it.

Comment: Okay. I really appreciate your effort. I've a lot of homework here to do, some I've done but some just prove difficult to solve. Thanks again